# how do I build a dictionary data inside a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this program:

```
def file(fname):
    lines = open(fname).read().splitlines()
    return(lines)
print(file('venue.txt'))
```

And it came out like this which I change into list:

```
['room 1,  10,  250']
```

How do I build a dictionary data with it, so that it can be like this:

```
[{'name': 'room 1', 'max': 10, 'cost': 250}]
```

Some clue maybe for me to build it.
Thanks

Edited:

```
def file(fname):
    lines = open(fname).read().splitlines()
    new = []
    for i in lines:
        split = i.split(', ')
        new.append({'name':split[0],'max':split[1],'cost':split[2]})
    return(new)   
print(file('venue.txt'))
```

It prints:

```
new.append({'name':split[0],'max':split[1],'cost':split[2]})
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
def file(fname):
   lines = open(fname).read().splitlines()
   return(lines)
headers = ["name", "max", "cost"]
data1 = [re.split(",\s+", i) for i in file("venue.txt")]
final_data = [{a:b for a, b in zip(headers, data} for data in data1]
print(final_data)
```

Comment: @Joehan you have to print `final_data`. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: yes..it works..thanks... but it only prints one data ...how about if it is more than one.....data = re.split(",\s+", file("venue.txt")[0])...i change the value 0 to other number it also print the other data...how do i get all of the data print in one time?...thanks...sorry if i ask to much @Ajax1234

Comment: @Joehan No problem at all! Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

If they are separated by `',  '` you can use the [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on `',  '`.
Will return an array with the separated items.

For your example:

```
current_list = ['room 1,  10,  250']
split = current_list[0].split(',  ')
new_list = [{'name': split[0], 'max': int(split[1]), 'cost': int(split[2])}]
print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'room 1', 'max': 10, 'cost': 250}]
```

For a larger list:

```
current_list = ['room 1,  10,  250', 'room 2,  30,  500','room 3,  50,  850']
new_list = []
for i in current_list:
    split = i.split(',  ')
    new_list.append({'name': split[0], 'max': int(split[1]), 'cost': int(split[2])})

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'room 1', 'max': 10, 'cost': 250}, {'name': 'room 2', 'max': 30, 'cost': 500}, {'name': 'room 3', 'max': 50, 'cost': 850}]
```

Comment: Use `int(split[1])` and `int(split[2])` to convert those to integers.